# Identyfing TOC entries with REGEX patterns

Tags: regex

Im a relatively new in the regex area:
I need some help identifying the following patterns:

```
1. Scope  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  . . .  4
2. References  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  . . 5
2.1 Normative References  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 6
2.1.3 Informative References  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 7
```

need to have capture in one hand the group (2.1.3 Informative References) and (Page number)
I have now some regex that capture either one or the other but not the both of them.

i want to know if i can do this just by using regrex or should i just programtically parse the lines..
Thanks for all!

Comment: Well, give us the regular expressions you have, and we'll see what we can do to help.  (http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Also, we need to know what language you're using - not all Regular expressions are created equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that should work:

```
/^([\d\.]+\s+[\w\s]+?)[\s\.]+(\d+)$/
```

Capture group $1 would return "2.1.3 Informative References" and $2 the page number.

Answer (score 0):

```
/([\d.]+[^.]+)[.\s]+(\d)/
```

Depending on your Regex engine, you should be able to extract the the heading and the page number of each line from the first and second groups, respectively.